# Flex wrap and justify content not working

Tags: html, css, flexbox

When I resize the screen the circles are not wrapping, even with `flex-wrap: wrap`.
Also `justify-content: space-evenly` is not working.

```css
.game-canvas {
    height: 450px;
    width: 850px;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
.tree-row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}
.base-tree {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.base-tree:nth-child(1) {
    background: green;
}
.base-tree:nth-child(2) {
    background: blue;
}
.base-tree:nth-child(3) {
    background: black;
}
.item {
    height: 50px;
    background: wheat;
    width: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Tree game</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main1.css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div id="game" class="canvas-container">
                <div id="game-canvas" class="game-canvas">
                    <div class="tree-row" id="tree-row">
                        <div class="base-tree">
                            <div class="item"></div>
                            <div class="item"></div>
                            <div class="item"></div>
                            <div class="item"></div>
                            <div class="item"></div>
                            <div class="item"></div>
                            <div class="item"></div>
                            <div class="item"></div>
                            <div class="item"></div>
                            <div class="item"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="base-tree">
                            <div class="item"></div>
                            <div class="item"></div>
                            <div class="item"></div>
                            <div class="item"></div>
                            <div class="item"></div>
                            <div class="item"></div>
                            <div class="item"></div>
                            <div class="item"></div>
                            <div class="item"></div>
                            <div class="item"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="base-tree">
                            <div class="item"></div>
                            <div class="item"></div>
                            <div class="item"></div>
                            <div class="item"></div>
                            <div class="item"></div>
                            <div class="item"></div>
                            <div class="item"></div>
                            <div class="item"></div>
                            <div class="item"></div>
                            <div class="item"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have given `width: 850px;` to `.game-canvas`.
So this element is taking 850px width and is not affected by screen size or screen resize.

A better approach can be using screen dependant width(instead of absolute width).
I modified one line in your original snippet, added `width: 80vw;` and it is working now.
Hope it helped.

```css
.game-canvas {
    height: 450px;
    width: 80vw;
    border: 2px solid black;
}
.tree-row {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}
.base-tree {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.base-tree:nth-child(1) {
    background: green;
}
.base-tree:nth-child(2) {
    background: blue;
}
.base-tree:nth-child(3) {
    background: black;
}
.item {
    height: 50px;
    background: wheat;
    width: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
        <title>Tree game</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main1.css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div id="game" class="canvas-container">
                <div id="game-canvas" class="game-canvas">
                    <div class="tree-row" id="tree-row">
                        <div class="base-tree">
                            <div class="item"></div>
                            <div class="item"></div>
                            <div class="item"></div>
                            <div class="item"></div>
                            <div class="item"></div>
                            <div class="item"></div>
                            <div class="item"></div>
                            <div class="item"></div>
                            <div class="item"></div>
                            <div class="item"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="base-tree">
                            <div class="item"></div>
                            <div class="item"></div>
                            <div class="item"></div>
                            <div class="item"></div>
                            <div class="item"></div>
                            <div class="item"></div>
                            <div class="item"></div>
                            <div class="item"></div>
                            <div class="item"></div>
                            <div class="item"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="base-tree">
                            <div class="item"></div>
                            <div class="item"></div>
                            <div class="item"></div>
                            <div class="item"></div>
                            <div class="item"></div>
                            <div class="item"></div>
                            <div class="item"></div>
                            <div class="item"></div>
                            <div class="item"></div>
                            <div class="item"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define width to make flex-wrap work.

add width like 300px to class "base-tree" and check.
also, you might want to remove justify-content from this class because if any row has less number to fill the row, it will be separated with a huge gap.

proof:
[image]

Comment: no it is  not working

Comment: I updated the answer with proof of working. Please check